# Can't seem to get two elements to be side-by-side

Tags: html, css

Here is what my webpage looks like:
[image]

As I highlighted in the picture, I'm trying to move the balance element to the right side.

I am trying to use the `display:inline-block` tag to do this.

Here is my CSS and HTML... what am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
/* Game box */
.gamebox{
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
}

/* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="noselection">

<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Play</a></li>
    <li><a href="deposit.php"><i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Deposit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Withdraw</a></li>
    <li><a href="faucet.php"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>Faucet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#support"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>Help & Support</a></li>
    <?php echo $accountButton; ?>
    <li class='right' id="top-balance"><a href=''></a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="gamebox">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i>itcoin dice game</h1>
        <div class="error" id="error">You don't have anymore bitcoins left. Why not deposit some more?</div>
        <form id="index">
            Bet
            <br>
            <span>
                <input id="userbet" onkeyup="checkBet()" value="100" type="text" name="bet" autocomplete="off">
                <span id="beterror" class="errortext">That bet is not a valid bet.</span>
                <span id="x2" class="timestwo" onclick="doubleBet()">x2</span>
                <span id="/2" class="dividetwo" onclick="divideBet()">/2</span>
            </span>
            <br>
            <span>
            Chance<br>
            <input id ="userchance" onkeydown="checkChance()" value="50" type="text" name="chance" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="chanceerror" class="errortext">That is not a valid chance.</span>
            </span>
            <br>
            <h3 id="payout">Payout: Loading...</h3>
            <script>var username = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['username']); ?>;</script>
            <script>var hash = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['hash']); ?>;</script>
            <button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll(username, hash);" style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="Images/dice.png"> Roll dice!</button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" id="autobet" onclick="setAutoBet(true)"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Autobet</button>
        <div class="autobet-mode" id="autobet-mode">
            <h3 id="auto-bet-start-text">Please set your auto bet settings, then click 'Start rolling'!".</h3>
            <button type="button" id="start-autobet" onclick="startAutoBet()">Start rolling!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="balance">
        <h3 id="balance">Balance: Loading...</h3>
    </div>

</div>

<?php echo $script; ?>

</body>
```

UPDATE:
Reducing the .balance width to 40% fixed the issue, but how can I now force it up?
[image]

Comment: you are making width 50% and adding padding to it makes its width more than 50%, try changing the width or padding.

Comment: add  box-sizing: border-box; to both the classes and give a try

Comment: try float:left; on both the classes.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Your first solution worked, but read the edit/update I made on the post. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You can add float:right to .balance class

Comment: hi try this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing2

Comment: Worked, you might want to put your first solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code
add box-sizing: border-box; property to both the classes.

CSS

```
.gamebox, .balance{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for below structure,

what happens here is when you apply fixed width to div and them apply padding and margin so your element width gets increased

so better you create another child container and assign padding margin over there

```css
.gamebox, .balance{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
.gamebox-inner, .balance-inner{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="gamebox">
  <div class="gamebox-inner">
  a
  </div>
</div>
<div class="balance">
  <div class="balance-inner">
  b
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try flexbox as follows.

```
<div id="container">
<div class ="first">first</div>
<div class="second">second</div>
</div>
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;enter code here
    border: 1px solid black;
    backgroud-color:red;
    display:flex;
}
.first {
  background-color:blue;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  flex:1;
}
.second {
  background-color:green;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  flex:2;
}
```